# AngularJS+Restangular directive to load data

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm need load some data from user input and check is its not empty (for validate form, is exist user)
My code :

```
.directive('userExist', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
  return {
    link:  function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
       scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(){
         Restangular.one('users', userID).get().then(function(data){
           scope.newOrder.user = data;
           ctrl.$setValidity('userExist', true);
         });
       })
    }
  };
}])
```

but i got error:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BtrZH/5/. If you still can't solve your problem, make a plunkr/fiddle and we can try to help you further.

Comment: Please show controller and view code. Why you put this code in a directive? The Controller is the right place for model manipulations and operations.